# Recommend firewall for LAMP server?

Tags: firewall

I have two LAMP servers, one with Ubuntu 9.10 the other with Ubuntu 8.04.  Can someone recommend firewall software for them?  I was following the guide at http://library.linode.com/networking/arno-iptables-firewall-debian-lenny, but ran into errors:

```
/sbin/iptables: (1) iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I'd like to allow ports 22, 25, 80, 443, 993, 995 and 10000.

If you can also suggest a step by step guide to install the firewall too, that would be great

Comment: You must be getting that error for a certain firewall rule. I suggest you to attach the firewall rule to your question.

Comment: One important gotcha: In most cases, when you install a firewall on a remote server, you get yourself locked out of SSH in the process. Luckily Linode has a recovery shell for just that case -- use it to add permit rules for SSH in your firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my server (which, coincidentally to your link, is a Linode), I use a program called UFW as a pretty frontend to IPTables. It's as easy as `sudo aptitude install ufw` on both your Ubuntu installs (it's part of the core repository, at least on 9.10 Karmic). I think [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=823741) on the Ubuntu Forums should help quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Another option which also simplifies the iptables rule and policy process is shorewall, [more info](http://www.shorewall.net).

Answer (score 1):

+1 of UFW and Shorewall for more complicated uses. One thing more, if you enable a firewall, then you should really look at protecting yourself against brute-force login attempts to SSH. Motivation:

- The brute force attempt clutter up your logs so that you might miss a serious hack attempt in the noise.
- If your password is weak (it should not be) then a stupid brute-force hacker could get lucky.

One super-simple way of doing this is to use your firewall to limit SSH to connections where the source IP address is from your office / home ADSL / your other semi-trusted networks. A more flexible way is to do connection rate limiting, either with your firewall or with other deamons.

Comment: Can you do rate limiting with ufw or apt? Or, should I go with something like fail2ban?